# DataPusher Production Deployment on CKAN 2.8 - OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ckan

I followed the official doc for deploying DataPusher to a production environment (https://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/deployment.html) but am getting `OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database [SQL: u'INSERT INTO jobs...`

I recognize this error is more to do with SQLAlchemy, namely the apache2 www-user user does not have permission to write to the SQLite database that the wsgi DataPusher app uses to keep track of jobs. I have limited experience with wsgi apps so I'm not really sure where to start with debugging...

I followed the official documentation to a T, however it's worth noting that I am replacing this with what was a functioning DataPusher *development* installation on the same server. I believe I have removed everything related to the development install.

Also worth noting is that `/usr/lib/ckan/default` points to `/home/ubuntu/ckan/lib/default` for an inexplicable reason. Also I believe this was a source install rather than a package install (hence my needing to deploy DataPusher).

I have tried adapting the documentation for the ckan directory being in /home/ubuntu, however I don't think this should matter since /usr/lib/ckan/default still points to the same effective location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to `chmod 777` (or the like) the sqlite (`.db`) file that is specified in the `/etc/ckan/datapusher_settings.py` file.

For example, the datapusher_settings.py file has the line for SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI that points to `/tmp/job_store.db` by default.

So `sudo chmod 777 /tmp/job_store.db`. I don't think it's much a concern to 777 this particular file, but it's likely a less-open value will suffice (e.g. 655). It may be best to `chown` to apache since that is the only thing that should be accessing this sqlite file, much less editing it.

No issues from ckan being installed in a non-standard directory (in this case, since /usr/lib/ckan/default still directs to the ckan directory).